# PostScript: not able to execute a macro containing "run" command

Tags: postscript

Trying make some PostScript functions which I can use later, I need to store those functions (processes in PostScript lingo) in separate files. There is a run command

> (foo.bar) run

you can use to do so. but I can't get it to work. 
this is a sample of a function (itopc.ps):

```
% this function converts inches to points
/itopc {72 mul} def
```

and this is a sample of a main script ([from here](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/postscript/)):

```
%!
(itopc.ps) run

newpath
1 itopc 2 itopc moveto
200 250 lineto
100 300 lineto
2 setlinewidth
stroke
showpage
```

and this is the error I get using gsview on windows 10:

```
Error: /invalidfileaccess in --run--
Operand stack:
   (itopc.ps)   (r)
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1983   1   3   %oparray_pop   1982   1   3   %oparray_pop   1966   1   3   %oparray_pop   1852   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   1983   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1212/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:82/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory

--- Begin offending input ---
```

the main code and then

```
--- End offending input ---
file offset = 0
gsapi_run_string_continue returns -101
```

P.S. It seams like Ghostscript is able to run this script/macro, perfectly fine. but GSview and mac OS X automatic Preview ps to pdf converter are not able to do so!
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figure the issue out. As [this page](http://umech.mit.edu/people/aja/linux/postscript.php) has explained, many official PostScript interpreters do not support "run" command for security reasons. At least Apple Preview and Adobe products do not. But GhosScript can. you may just open the file using command:

> gs foo.ps

on unix like machines and on a Windows machine you may use the [PS_View](http://psview.sourceforge.net/) app installed with Ghostscript or [Samutrapdf](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html)

with ps2pdf as [this post explains](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286025/error-invalidfileaccess-in-run-when-you-are-using-external-files-with-pst) you may use the command below to compile the PDF:

> ps2pdf -dNOSAFER foo.ps

For GSView, on Windows you can go to Options>Advance Configure... and add

> -dNOSAFE

to GhostScript Options.

Comment: If you go into the preferences, you should find "gs command". Either add -dNOSAFER at the end, or remove the -dSAFER that's in there.

Comment: I found the setting on windows, but have no idea how to fix this on a mac

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical configuration for document processing. For ghostscript you can add `-dNOSAFER` to the command line to re-enable the `run` operator. In GSview you can go into the options and add this to the gs command. Not sure how to do it with Preview.

Comment: with ghostscript I did not have any issues without that flag. can you please tell me how I can "add this to the gs command"?